# MongooseCastError: Cast to date failed for value "{ '$lt': 2021-05-03T20:30:00.011Z }" at path "endDate"

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose with NestJS.
I try to get all event that are passed with the following query

```
this.eventModel.find({
      endDate: { $lt: new Date() },
      status: 'published',
    });
```

But I get the following error

```
CastError: Cast to date failed for value "{ '$lt': 2021-05-03T20:31:00.008Z }" at path "endDate"
```

It's weird cause the date format should be OK

Comment: could you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` instead of `updateMany` method.

```
this.eventModel.find({
   endDate: { $lt: new Date() },
   status: 'published',
});
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I already use find, I just copied and past wrong piece of code.